# Minimum screen dimensions in pygame without ever letting the screen get too small

Tags: python, pygame

For my pygame screen, I have a bit of code that doesn't let the screen get to small, something like this: (not the full code but the relevant parts)

```
import pygame
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1200), pygame.RESIZABLE)
window_x, window_y = 1000, 1200
# (in main while loop)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    window_x, window_y = window.get_size()
    if window_x < 500 or window_y < 600:
        window = pygame.display.set_mode((max(500, window_x), max(600, window_y)), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

This works fine, but you can still make the screen tiny, it just pops back to 500x600 if you let go. For example, on a google screen, you can't make the screen too small, it stops at a certain point even if you haven't let go of your mouse. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: are you comparing windows created in different windowing systems? (ie. Google chromeOS vs Microsoft Windows or the Google Chrome browser under the same one)?

Comment: This is just for a pygame window, I was using chrome as an example because it never shrinks below a certain size. Looking at examples online it looks like this is the best I can do

Answer (score 0):

I don't certainly find any mistake in the logic of this code but have a suggestion that:

```
window_x, window_y = window.get_size()
    if window_x < 500 or window_y < 600:
        window = pygame.display.set_mode((max(500, window_x), max(600, window_y)), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Put this piece of code outside your event loop but in the main while loop because you want to check it all the times and not only when an event occurs.